# Ask Google to remove email ALIAS (from a domain I own) from a GMAIL account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google

**Facts**:

1. I have a Google Apps account with my domain: `example.com`
2. I created a user for my domain: `alice@example.com`
3. Alice registers `alice@example.com` as an email alias for her gmail account: `alice@gmail.com`
4. Three years later, Alice leaves `example.com`
5. I delete her `alice@example.com` account from the Google Apps account. As expected, she can no longer get emails addressed to `alice@example.com`.
6. However, she can still send emails from `alice@example.com` using her gmail account since she keeps the email alias on it.

**Question**: is there a procedure to ask Google to remove that email alias from her account since I own the `example.com` domain?

*Thanks!*